# JavaScript event overwrite

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an `onclick` event handler function like

`onclick="add(this.id,x,y);"` , embedded in HTML. The `add` function, after making its main job, has to overwrite the `onclick` event handler like:

```
function add(id,x,y) {
element = getElementById("id");
z = y*x; //just an example
element.onclick = 'add('+id+','+x+','+z+');';
}
```

So when next time the `onclick` is called `add(id,x,z);` should run, but unfortunately it's not working this way. Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Comment: You should consider passing `this` as a parameter instead of `this.id`; what happens if the element does not have an id? You can then alter `add()` as follows: `function add(element, x, y) { z = y*x; element.onclick = 'add(this,' + x + ', ' + z + ');';`

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
element = getElementById("id");
```

should be:

```
element = document.getElementById(id); // without quotes!
```

Comment: More specifically, it's getting the element which has the actual name "id", rather than the value of the `id` parameter.

Comment: I did some further testing. Any value that is assigned to element.onclick, string, integer, function, whatever, stoppes my script. So when i put an alert('asd'); after the assignment for testint, that alert() never runs :S